# C# - Dns.GetHostEntry: host name is empty or not correct

Tags: c#, dns, network-programming

My PC is connected to a LAN which gateway is 80.0.0.1 
When I use this code:

```
IPHostEntry hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry("80.0.0.1");
Var name = hostEntry.HostName;
```

it gives me the name of a global Internet domain (hari-core-2a-xe-800-0.network.virginmedia.net), not the name of my local host.
How can I get the right name of the local host.
I know that there are reserved domains like 10.0.x.x that can be used with LANs, but I don't want to change the LAN gateway. If I can change it in my LAN, I can't force all users of my application to change theirs if they have similar conflictions.
Is there any work around?

Edit:
I changed the LAN to 9.0.0.1 for testing. Dns.GetHostEntry threw "No such host is known" exception. It fails to get the name of the AP. and android devices connected to the LAN. Any solution?
Note: Advanced IP Scanner also can't get the names of the devices. It displays tha IP ot each device as a name.

Comment: Looks like Group Policy is being used in your corporate network.  Local host is defined in the windows host file : C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts.  The host table is an array so normally you use : IPAddress ipAddress = hostEntry.AddressList[0];

Comment: I do not thinl so. I changed the LAN to 9.0.0.1 for testing. Dns.GetHostEntry threw "No such host is known" exception. It fails to get the name of the AP. and android devices connected to the LAN. Any solution?
Note: Advanced IP Scanner also can't get the names of the devices. It displays tha IP ot each device as a name. 
.

Comment: Use computer name instead of IP in Dns.GetHostEntry() method.  You group policy in network isn't setup to find devices by IP.  IP requires routing tables in PCs to be setup correctly including mask.  Going by names the DCHP server to route connection to devices which is setup properly.

Comment: I think TL-WR840N  may be the problem. Some how it prevents DNS from getting correct names.

Comment: Found manual : http://static.tp-link.com/res/down/doc/TL-WR840N_V2_UG.pdf.  I had job for 5 years configuring a intranet network.  Know all the issues and terminology and specifications.  Still can't figure out how to configure these routers will all the options.  Best to talk to vendor support.  See manual : Appendix A: FAQ page 89
Enabled AP isolation pages 42-43
DHCP Settings page 45
ARP List page 75

Comment: Thanks for your concern and help. I will look at the manual. But I think as a programmer: I can't go to every user to adjust his AP settings. Even most users don't know anything about AP configuration! Is there any other programmatic way th get the correct names?.. Any protocol that communicats with the device directly and asks for its name and MAC?

Comment: Not if the router is blocking or changing the IP.  Most users will not be using your router. Typical settings for any router is to block multicast from going between different subnets,  So if your devices are in a different subnet then you will not get ping.  So the solution in your case would be to change the mask of the subnet in the router so devices are in the same subnet as your PC.  In this case YOU configured the router wrong.  if user also didn't configure their network properly it would need to be fixed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution that works for me:

1. I changed the gateway IP for my LAN to 10.0.1.1 to avoid conflictions.
2. I use DNS.GetHostEntry to get the name.
3. If name is empty (happens in LAN with some AP models) or equals to the IP address, I suppose this is the IP of an AP or a router. I will try to connect to the webpage http:\[ip] and use the title of the webpage as a name (The title will be the device model).
   This works with devices that displays login page. If the device wants to supply the username and password with the request, an WebException occurs and I can get the response.Headers["WWW-Authenticate"] which contains the string:  Basic realm="X", where X is a string that describes the device.
4. If name is still empty, I get the MAC address show it as a name.

You can find the code (C# & VB.NET) in the PingThread Class in the IPScanner Applicationm here:
http://www.mediafire.com/file/1fku7fz7ytr8p59/IPScanner.zip

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get your local host, why don't you create the `IPHostEntry` object for local host then?

```
IPHostEntry hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry("127.0.0.1");
```

Comment: Sorry if I couldn't explain it. 80.0.0.1 is the gateway of the AP that my PC connects to. I got wrong names for all other devices in this LAN, because the confliction with the Internet Domain.

Comment: Update: I changed the LAN to 9.0.0.1 for testing. Dns.GetHostEntry threw "No such host is known" exception. It fails to get the name of the AP. and android devices connected to the LAN. Any solution?
Note: Advanced IP Scanner also can't get the names of the devices. It displays tha IP ot each device as a name.