# Dns.GetHostEntry doesn't work in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

In my C# console application, if I run this code:

```
IPHostEntry entry = Dns.GetHostEntry(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.6.54"));
if (entry != null)
{
    var x = entry.HostName;
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

It prints `HOME-PC`

But If I run it in my Xamarin Forms application, on a physical Android device that is connected to the same network, `x` is `192.168.6.54`. Why?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31849285/c-sharp-dns-gethostentry-doesnt-return-names-of-mobile-devices-connected-to-wif

Comment: Maybe this link will help you ：https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44743311/c-sharp-dns-gethostentry-host-name-is-empty-or-not-correct